# Error during install extensions in Postgresql 9.2

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tried following:

```
sudo -u postgres psql <enter>
create extension "uuid-ossp";
```

but showing error: `ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/uuid-ossp": No such file or directory`

I have tried: `select version()`. It's showing my postgresql version `PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1, 64-bit`

Later tried to install extension `adminpack` using `create extension "adminpack"` but it's also throwing error: `ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/adminpack.control": No such file or directory`

I have tried `locate uuid-ossp` which gave me following result:

```
/usr/src/postgresql-9.2.4/contrib/uuid-ossp
/usr/src/postgresql-9.2.4/contrib/uuid-ossp/Makefile
/usr/src/postgresql-9.2.4/contrib/uuid-ossp/uuid-ossp--1.0.sql
/usr/src/postgresql-9.2.4/contrib/uuid-ossp/uuid-ossp--unpackaged--1.0.sql
/usr/src/postgresql-9.2.4/contrib/uuid-ossp/uuid-ossp.c
/usr/src/postgresql-9.2.4/contrib/uuid-ossp/uuid-ossp.control
/usr/src/postgresql-9.2.4/doc/src/sgml/uuid-ossp.sgml
/usr/src/postgresql-9.2.4/doc/src/sgml/html/uuid-ossp.html
```

`locate adminpack` is giving following result:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/adminpack.so
/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/adminpack--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/adminpack.control
/usr/src/postgresql-9.2.4/contrib/adminpack
/usr/src/postgresql-9.2.4/contrib/adminpack/Makefile
/usr/src/postgresql-9.2.4/contrib/adminpack/adminpack--1.0.sql
/usr/src/postgresql-9.2.4/contrib/adminpack/adminpack.c
/usr/src/postgresql-9.2.4/contrib/adminpack/adminpack.control
/usr/src/postgresql-9.2.4/doc/src/sgml/adminpack.sgml
/usr/src/postgresql-9.2.4/doc/src/sgml/html/adminpack.html
```

Comment: Please show the output of `select version()`. Also, *how, exactly, did you install PostgreSQL 9.2?*

Comment: @CraigRinger I have updated the post with version. It's showing: PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1, 64-bit

Comment: ... and the second thing I asked?

Comment: @CraigRinger Sorry. I am working in a server where my other colleague has installed postgresql there. He is on leave today. That's why I am doing his task.

Comment: Well, to sort this out, you first need to work out exactly how PostgreSQL was installed on the machine. Start with `dpkg -I /usr/local/bin/psql`, assuming that's where your `psql` is.

Comment: @CraigRinger I have successfully installed adminpack using your following answer (make and install). Thanks. But still struggling to create extension ossp-uuid which is my main purpose. It's showing `ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/uuid-ossp": No such file or directory` error again. `dpkg -I /usr/local/bin/psql` is throwing error: `dpkg-deb: error: `/usr/local/bin/psql' is not a debian format archive`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46796/discussion-between-ray-and-craig-ringer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a wild guess, you've downloaded the PostgreSQL 9.2 sources to `/usr/src`, unpacked it, configured it, compiled and installed it ... but not installed [the contribs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib.html).

If so, from the PostgreSQL source dir:

```
cd contrib && make && sudo make install
```

If you want updated PostgreSQL releases, it's usually better to get them packaged unless you need/want to make source code changes. See http://yum.postgresql.org/, http://apt.postgresql.org/, http://www.postgresql.org/download/, ...

**Update**: Some of these have dependencies. E.g. for `uuid-ossp` you must install the ossp-uuid lib first:

```
apt-get install libossp-uuid-dev
```

*then* compile and install `contrib/uuid-ossp`:

```
cd contrib/uuid-ossp && make && make install
```

Check the error output from the `make` step for more info, and if in doubt, remember, Google. The *first* error is usually the most important.

Comment: output of make. I think it's compiled. `/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib/postgresql'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/postgresql/extension'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/postgresql/extension'
/bin/sh ../../config/install-sh -c -m 755  uuid-ossp.so '/usr/lib/postgresql/uuid-ossp.so'
/bin/sh ../../config/install-sh -c -m 644 ./uuid-ossp.control '/usr/share/postgresql/extension/'
/bin/sh ../../config/install-sh -c -m 644 ./uuid-ossp--1.0.sql ./uuid-ossp--unpackaged--1.0.sql  '/usr/share/postgresql/extension/'`

Comment: Output of make install `/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib/postgresql'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/postgresql/extension'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/postgresql/extension'
/bin/sh ../../config/install-sh -c -m 755  uuid-ossp.so '/usr/lib/postgresql/uuid-ossp.so'
/bin/sh ../../config/install-sh -c -m 644 ./uuid-ossp.control '/usr/share/postgresql/extension/'
/bin/sh ../../config/install-sh -c -m 644 ./uuid-ossp--1.0.sql ./uuid-ossp--unpackaged--1.0.sql  '/usr/share/postgresql/extension/'`

Comment: but still showing the same error: `ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/uuid-ossp": No such file or directory`

Comment: @ray Looks like it's installed in `/usr/share` not `/usr/local/share`. Bizarre. Did you change anything else, e.g. re-running `./configure` ?

Comment: when make was giving error I have tried `./configure --prefix=/usr --with-ossp-uuid` from google. Then make gave above output.

Comment: @ray Well, your PostgreSQL is installed in *`/usr/local/`* not in `/usr`. So that's the problem.

Comment: So before I run CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp"; can I change the directory to find uuid-ossp?

Comment: @ray No, re-run configure with the correct install path, "make install" into the correct location, and it'll work. When your co-worker comes back, smack them one for me.

Comment: finally it has been solved using your suggestion to run ./configure in `/usr/local`. Thanks a lot man. I have already sent email to Agnes (culprit) to be prepared for smack!!

Answer (score 1):

For those who come across this and are installing a specific version of Postgresql (e.g. 9.6):

Make sure you install the same version of **contrib**:

```
yum install postgresql96-server postgresql96-contrib
```

When I originally install **postgresql96-server** using directions from PostgreSQL website, it didn't mention installing **contrib**, so I installed the wrong version later on - forgetting I didn't use the default version in the CentOS repos.